# Насторойка intellisense в vscode. Автодополнения отображаются в одну строку

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Автодополнения в vscode стали отображатся в одну строку. Хотелось бы вернуть отображение по умолчанию. Не могу найти настройку которая отвечает за этот параметр.

У меня вот так:

[image: У меня вот так.]

А хотелось бы вот так:

[image: Хотелось бы вот так.]

Comment: а в чем разница?

Comment: За уголок пробовали мышкой тянуть?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Помогло, спасибо.